# Hide select box multiple options

Tags: html, html-select

I want show the select box option which will show only one value and hides rest of the values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style `<option>` using `display:none`,

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
  <option style = "display: none" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a class with display none as style and apply it to the options you need not want to show.

Comment: It worked for me.. but it seems it is not hiding in certain browsers. For uniformity across browsers remove the unnecessary options before you set them to the select tag. You can add them back and reset the options when you need it. Hope this is your requirement.